# How to append a unusual checklist in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to create a smaller script compared to mine.

My current code:

```
var1 = IntVar()
var1_2 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var2_2 = IntVar()

self.Check1 = Checkbutton(main, text="Option 1", variable=var1)
self.Check1.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = W)

self.Check1_2 = Checkbutton(main, variable=var1_2)
self.Check1_2.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)

self.Check2 = Checkbutton(main, text="Option 2", variable=var2)
self.Check2.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)

self.Check2_2 = Checkbutton(main, variable=var2_2)
self.Check2_2.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
```

this is very long, and I know I can shorten it. but not sure how. Here is where I got to and stopped, because I am not too sure where to go from there:

```
info = ["Option 1", "Option 2"]

vars = []
for i in info:
 var = IntVar(value=0)
 vars.append(var)
 btn = Checkbutton(main, text=i,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

info = ["Option 1", "Option 2","Option 3", "Option 4"]

vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    btn = tk.Checkbutton(main, text=i, var = var)     
    btn.grid(column=idx%2,row=idx//2)

main.mainloop()
```

I've added enumerate to the for loop so that each item gets given a number `idx` i.e. 0,1,2,3 etc.

I've also used some simple calculations to position each checkbox based on an assumption that you want two checkboxes per row using the modulus and integer divide operators.

Given your comments on my original answer, I suspect you want to use radio buttons instead of check buttons. These support the option of only one of them being on at a time. See the below example for how to achieve that.
Radio buttons support having a different value stored to the IntVar depending which one is selected and will uncheck an option if the other is selected.

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

info = ["Option 1", "Option 2","Option 3", "Option 4"]

vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = tk.Label(main,text=i)
    btnYes = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="Yes", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNo = tk.Radiobutton(main, text="No", variable=var, value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=0,row=idx)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but I tried having double check boxes for each check list, they'll represent `yes`,`no`. Thats why I have vars with `_2`

Comment: @Sackoverflow None of your words in your post said that was what you were trying to achieve. For this you probably want radio buttons instead of check boxes. I'll find an example